# UIRefreshControl flicker with self sizing cells

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, uirefreshcontrol

I'm trying to use `TableViewController` with `UIRefreshControl` and self sizing `cells`.

Randomly strange flickering appears. What I'm doing wrong?

Video - http://cl.ly/0r1M1B3b0Z2I

Sample project - https://github.com/nspavlo/RefreshControll

Comment: Having the same problem, would love to find an answer!

Comment: Did you find an answer for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Provided github project is empty. My best gues is that you are looking it in simulator. Try it on real device as simulators have some dificulties with 1px rendering.

Comment: Git repo. updated.
Tested on up to date iPhone 6 - same issue.